# Оптимизация PNG на PHP с помощью GD

Tags: php, изображения, gd, png

Можно ли сжать картинку PNG, не утратив при этом её прозрачность и сохранив в новый файл, как это делается? 
Просмотр десятка тематических статей не увенчался успехом

Comment: сжать - уменьшить размер? ширину и высоту?  или уменьшить объем файла?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о том, чтобы оптимизировать файл изображения, сократив его объем, то gd так не умеет, я рекомендую использовать утилиту optipng

http://optipng.sourceforge.net/

синтаксис optipng [options] file

Если речь о банальном уменьшении размера картинки, то нужно просто установить blending mode в false, опцию save alpha channel в true:

```
<?php
 $newImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);
 imagealphablending($newImg, false);
 imagesavealpha($newImg,true);
 $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
 imagefilledrectangle($newImg, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $transparent);
 imagecopyresampled($newImg, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight,
                      $imgInfo[0], $imgInfo[1]);
?>
```